# Laravel: Relationships User hasOne Group, Group hasMany User

Tags: laravel

I want to create a relationship between two tables "users" and "groups", in this relationship, a user belongs to only one group, and the group has multiple users, to solve this, how should i design the table? Need a table "group_user"?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. Probably helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use just two tables which names are "users" and "groups". Because one user have only one group. So there is no required to any pivot table.

Tables columns should be like this:

**Users**: id, name, group_id

**Groups**: id, name

In the User entity you should do relation like this:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Group::class, 'group_id', 'id' );
}
```

And in the Group entity:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany( User::class, 'group_id', 'id' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, initially I also thought so, the next thought made me not sure this, perhaps things are not as complicated as I thought.

Comment: Yes it's quite basic relation :)